# Create and resize dynamic array without C libraries?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc

Is there a way to actually create dynamic arrays in C without having to use the stdlib?

`Malloc` requires the `stdlib.h` library, I am not allowed to use this in my project.

If anyone has any ideas, please share? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can always roll your own...

Comment: wow, than you should write some assembly code

Answer (score 8):

`malloc` is not *just* a library, it is the way you interface with the Operating System to ask for more memory for the running process. Well, you could ask more memory and manage free/occupied memory yourself, but it would be wrong on many levels.

But, I am inclined to believe that your project is going to run in some kind of platform which does not have an operating system, is it?<sup>1</sup> In that case, the faster solution is to first allocate statically some memory in a big global array, and every time you need memory you would ask for a manager responsible for this big array.

Let me give you an example, for the sake of simplicity it will be tiny and not very functional, but it is a very good quick start.

```
typedef char bool;

#define BLOCK_SIZE 1024 //Each allocation must have in max 1kb
#define MAX_DATA 1024*1024*10  //Our program statically allocates 10MB
#define BLOCKS (MAX_DATA/BLOCK_SIZE)

typedef char Scott_Block[BLOCK_SIZE];

Scott_Block Scott_memory[BLOCKS];
bool Scott_used_memory[BLOCKS];

void* Scott_malloc(unsigned size) {
    if( size > BLOCK_SIZE )
        return NULL;
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;i<BLOCKS;++i) {
        if( Scott_used_memory[i] == 0 ) {
            Scott_used_memory[i] = 1;
            return Scott_memory[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Scott_free(void* ptr) {
    unsigned int pos = ((char*)(ptr)-Scott_memory[0])/BLOCK_SIZE;
    printf("Pos %d\n",pos);
    Scott_used_memory[pos] = 0;
}
```

I wrote this code to show how to emulate a memory manager. Let me point out a few improvements that may be done to it.

First, the Scott_used_memory could be a *bitmap* instead of a `bool` array. 
Second, it does not allocate memory bigger than BLOCK_SIZE, it should search for consecutives blocks to create a bigger block. But for that you would need more control data to tell how much blocks an allocated `void*` occupies.
Third, the way free memory is searched (linearly) is very slow, usually the blocks creates a link list of free blocks.

But, like I said, this is a great quick start. And depending on your needs this may fulfill it very well.

<sup>1</sup> If not, then you have absolutely **no reason** to not use malloc.

Answer (score 2):

Well why not this program (C99)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sizet, i;
   printf("Enter size:");
   scanf("%d",&sizet);
   int array[sizet];
   for(i = 0; i < sizet; i++){ 
     array[i] = i;
   }
   for(i = 0; i < sizet; i++){
     printf("%d", array[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Like a boss! :-)

Comment: Will the stack be dynamically re-sized to fit the requested array?

Comment: @AndréPuel Yep. `SUB ESP, EAX` ;-)

Comment: @AndréPuel http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html it is standard C :-)

Comment: I swear I had a code that did not compile a few weeks ago because it was using exactly that... Let me find it in my git history.

Comment: @AndréPuel that's because you did not compile your program with `-std=c99` prefix

Comment: @Aniket It was a C++11 code, actually. The error only showed up on clang, not on gcc

Comment: Why did you not just use `std::vector<>`? @AndréPuel :-)

Comment: @Aniket, not my code... You would not believe with what I have to face everyday ¬¬

Comment: what do you have to face everyday? :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24056/discussion-between-andre-puel-and-aniket)